# Defining and calling a function instead of in-line function for click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick

I was able to define an inline function for the click event on any node, however i was trying to make my code a bit cleaner so i wanted to declare my function and just call it for the click event.

here is the inline version:

```
node.on("click", function(n){
  var active = !n.active ? true :false;
  console.log(active);
})
```

here is the version with the function call:

```
node.on("click", linkSwitch(n));

linkSwitch(n){
  var active = !n.active ? true :false;
  console.log(active);
}
```

for the function call version ONLY. i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
```

i don't know why??

Comment: Where do you get this error? because normally if `n` would be undefined you would get an error on this: `n.active` which would say something like, `active` can't be accessed from undefined... So, where do you exactly get this error? Try to log at the beginning of the function the value of `n`.

Comment: Maybe would be a good idea if you can put a bit more code, so that we can see the running context. because at first view, it seams there is nothing wrong with the first function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this...

```
node.on("click", function(n){
```

... that parameter `n` corresponds to the first argument that D3 automatically passes to the anonymous function, which is the *datum*.

However, when you do this:

```
node.on("click", linkSwitch(n));
```

You have two problems:

1. Your `n` is obviously undefined, so nothing strange about that error, which is expected;
2. You are not calling the function on click: you're calling the function *immediately* and returning its value.

**Solution**: it should be just:

```
node.on("click", linkSwitch)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const data = [{
  name: "foo",
  active: true
}, {
  name: "bar",
  active: true
}, {
  name: "baz",
  active: true
}];

const paragraphs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(d => d.name);

paragraphs.on("click", linkSwitch);

function linkSwitch(n) {
  var active = !n.active ? true : false;
  console.log(active);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Some additional issues:

- You're missing the `function` in your function declaration;
- The logic in the function can be shortened to `var active = !n.active`

Comment: Thank you so much!! sorry about forgetting "function" in my deceleration.